# How can I install poppler on Digital Ocean? (poppler not found using pdf2image in production)

Tags: python, fastapi, pdf2image

I am using pdf2image to apply an OCR to PDFs files, but when using it in production, i have an issue telling me that poppler was not found in path.

N.B : I am using Digital Ocean

I tried to add a setup.py file with the following :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    scripts=['config/packages.sh']
)
```

with packages.sh is :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install poppler-utils -y 
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr -y
```

But it seems that heruko/python is taking only requirements.txt into consideration.
Any solution to this ?

Comment: "Issue with" doesn't narrow down something enough that people can tell if they have _the same_ issue, which is the purpose of a title. I've tried to edit to do a better job of that.

Comment: Speaking to content rather than form: `scripts` is not a script that setup.py runs -- that's not what it does, not what it _ever has_ done. It's a script that a `python setup.py install` _copies into the PATH_. As for the rest of it -- if Digital Ocean intends you to have sudo access to your instances, you should have a deployment method that lets you run arbitrary commands without your `setup.py` being involved. If they don't intend you to have that access, `sudo` won't work whether or not something in your `setup.py` tries to run it.